# Error on SQL Query (UPDATE) - Error varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to execute a query on SQL Server:

```
UPDATE Clientes
SET CodigoCanal = IdDelegacion
WHERE (CodigoEmpresa = '1')
```

It is very simple, really. It's just to copy column A on column B (CodigoCanal and IdDelegacion).

But it gives me this error:
la conversion del tipo de datos varchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera del intervalo

```
The conversion of the varchar data type into datetime produced a value outside the range
```

UPDATE:
I add pictures of both column's properties:

[image: First column]
    <sup>**First column**</sup>

[image: Second Column]
    <sup>**Second Column**</sup>

Comment: It would be great if you could provide the error message in english..

Comment: Please post the definition for the `Clientes` table.

Comment: Your error message is talking about out of range dates arising from a conversion.  But, I wouldn't expect to see this from your update query.  Are you sure this query is what generated the error message?

Comment: passing varchar data in datetime column

Comment: Weird, but looks like "CodigoCanal" or CodigoEmpresa is a datetime column. Is there any chance that you have created the table with wrong columns types? I think Tim Biegeleisen made a good point to check.

Comment: looks like CodigoCanal  is a date data type and IdDelegacion  is a varchar, IdDelegacion  has a value in it that cannot be implicitly converted to a date

Comment: Hi!
This is message in english: the conversion of the varchar data type into datetime produced a value outside the range @holder

Comment: Friends, Both columns are varchar, I promise!

Comment: @AlbertSunyer, if both columns are varchar, it is likely there's an update trigger on the table which is causing the error.

Comment: I added pictures on question.

Comment: what is the datatype of CodigoEmpresa?

Comment: I can't see the pictures, they're blocked by my work.
Can you post the output of exec sp_coluimns please?

Answer (score 0):

Data tipes of your columns doesn't match. It looks like CordigoCanal is datetime and IdDelegacion varchar.

Comment: Please, see pictures attached on post

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you are using a datetime datatype at some point.
Looking at the definition of your columns CodigoCanal and IdDelegacion those are of type varchar. The only columns that might have the datetime data type are:

- Columns used in a trigger, as Dan Guzman mentioned
- The CodigoEmpresa  column (you did not post the definition here)

Answer (score 0):

All right.
I've checked on triggers, and there was 2 of them enabled.
I disabled them, ran the query and then enabled again ;)

Thank you for all your help!